# How would you reduce your collection of elements to just spans in JQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have been asked a couple of questions in regards to JQuery and I am not entirely sure on how to answer them?

1 How would you reduce your collection of elements to just spans?
2. Given you have found $('#anID'), how would you add context to a jquery selector to restrict the scope of search for one of its children?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I assume in 'reduce your collection of elements to just spans' you mean 'get all spans in page' - in that case, you can simply do `$('span')` (how awesome is that? :) ). For more information, visit [JQuery selector documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).
2. To find only decedents of an element, you can use [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) method, like this: `$('#anID').find('.child-selector')`

Comment: Thank you very much I had just gotten the .find() answer but the other one is very helpful :)

Comment: Then.. Accept this as answer? :)